# What size should my images be for a mobile site

Tags: html, css, mobile, jquery-mobile

We are designing a template for a mobile site and we got to the problem where we don't know what size a logo should be, or the background, etc.

We will use the Jquery mobile API and HTML5 / CSS3 which basically allows us to create the whole architecture of the site without worrying about the dimensions, but in terms of external assets like backgrounds and images we don't know what is the best size in order to be more compatible with most devices.

Comment: most images will never really be higher than 500px unless they are a background image, so you should have no trouble to write one media query based on devices that are 480px wide to shrink the image down so that it is 250px instead of 500px.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The iPhone 4S/5 has a high-resolution screen that's 640 pixels wide. Many Android smartphones top out at 720px wide, although some go up to 800px. Anything over that is probably considered a tablet.

The best thing you can do as far as wide compatibility, then, is a single CSS style:

```
img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; }
```

This will ensure that no matter what resolution the screen is, your images will be no larger than the element containing it. (When building a responsive site with mobile users in mind, your element widths, margins and padding should all be computed as percentages whenever possible.) Obviously it also means that you're downloading more image data than many phones will need, but if you're dealing with two-color logos, it's not much of a difference. As always, keep your images as few and as small as possible.

In addition, if you're not dealing with photos, you should look at SVG images. Since they're vector-based, they resize perfectly at any resolution, and [they're compatible with pretty much every browser except IE8 and Android 2.x](http://caniuse.com/#search=svg).

Comment: I tried that but whenever the mobile device (in this case the iphone) is flipped from vertical to horizontal, the image gets bigger instead of re-adjusting to the new percentage according to the device's width

Comment: That's a separate problem, then. Different `<meta>` tags exist to approach this issue.

Comment: Do you have any reference to look into this meta tags? thanks

Comment: You might start [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOS/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/UsingtheViewport/UsingtheViewport.html)

Comment: This helped me. You sir are a scholar!

Answer (score 4):

I am sure that the image size normally should not be more like it defines CSS media query standart.

This is a short list of CSS media query for the most popular devices of 2015-2016.

Just add into this list media quieres for new devices if you need.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
/**********
iPad 3
**********/
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}
/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1224px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen  and (min-width : 1824px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 568px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 375px) and (max-device-height: 667px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 6+ ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 414px) and (max-device-height: 736px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S3 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 2){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S4 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 320px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

/* Samsung Galaxy S5 ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : landscape) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}

@media only screen and (min-device-width: 360px) and (max-device-height: 640px) and (orientation : portrait) and (-webkit-device-pixel-ratio: 3){
/* Styles */
}
```

And also take a look at the older lists https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/ and https://gist.github.com/hs0ucy/3762901

Answer (score 0):

You have to use CSS media queries for this.
Take a look of this article here: http://davidwalsh.name/image-max-width

```
/* iphone */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) {
      img { max-width: 100%; }
}

/* ipad */
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 768px) and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
      img { max-width: 100%; }
}
```